# Android rotate TextView with own extended TextView class

Tags: android, rotation, textview

I would like to create a square based on the length of the text and be able to rotate it. I've extended the textview and change the onMeasure, but when I rotate it the text is draw in the upper part of the square. When it starts rotating the text doesn't rotate around it's own middle point.

The image below shows the result of the current situation in red and the desired situation in green. The yellow dot is the pivot point.

[image: Text image]

Thank you very much for your help!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyTextView extends TextView {

private int angle = 0;

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(),getMeasuredWidth());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());
    canvas.rotate(angle, canvas.getWidth()/2f, canvas.getHeight()/2f);
    getLayout().draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

public void setAngle(int textAngle) {
    angle = textAngle;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the Gravity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are two problems.

One the gravity isn't center so when it gets rotated it wont be where you expect it.

The other problem is that you want it to be rotated around the view size not the canvas size.  See below.

Note you may have to do some more tweaking as I didn't account for padding.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    private int angle = 75;

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getExtendedPaddingTop());
        canvas.rotate(angle, this.getWidth() / 2f, this.getHeight() / 2f);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    public void setAngle(int textAngle) {
        angle = textAngle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your help! I'm one step closer, but the only thing which still doesn't work is the gravity. Is this maybe because I've altered the onMeasure? Do you know that?

Comment: Can you post another picture showing what is happening?  Perhaps more code too?

Comment: I've made it simpler and now it works: I've changed the onDraw to simply: canvas.rotate(angle, canvas.getWidth() / 2f, canvas.getHeight() / 2f); super.onDraw(canvas); Now it works. Thanks  for your help!